# "Data Truncated" error in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, double

I am trying to UPDATE the data in the table named as 'schedulle'. But each time control goes to the conditional statements containing double values, i am getting error:

> Data truncated for column 'total' at row 1"    string

I am getting this error in the code bellow:

```
//Insert Data in Schedule
                    foreach (ScheduleData item in schedUpdate)
                    {
                        query = "UPDATE schedulle SET "
                            +" sch_day='"+ item.DayOfWeek + "',morning='"+ item.Morning + "',evening='"+ item.Evening + "',total='@t' WHERE emp_id_fk='"+global_ID+"'";
                        command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection, transaction);
                        if (item.Morning.Equals("set") && item.Evening.Equals("set"))
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", 5.0);
                        }
                        if (item.Morning.Equals("set") && item.Evening.Equals("unset"))
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", Convert.ToDouble(2.5));
                        }
                        if (item.Morning.Equals("unset") && item.Evening.Equals("set"))
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", 2.5);
                        }
                        if (item.Morning.Equals("unset") && item.Evening.Equals("unset"))
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", 0);
                        }
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

My database schema is as bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE payroll_db.schedulle (
  sch_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  emp_id_fk INT(11) NOT NULL,
  sch_day VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  morning VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unset',
  evening VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unset',
  total DOUBLE(10, 3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sch_id),
  INDEX emp_id_fk (emp_id_fk),
  CONSTRAINT schedulle_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (emp_id_fk)
    REFERENCES payroll_db.employee(emp_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 64
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 2340
CHARACTER SET ascii
COLLATE ascii_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;
```

Moreover, 'item' is an instance of ScheduleData class. ScheduleData class is mentioned bellow:

```
public class ScheduleData : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            private string dayOfWeek;
            public string DayOfWeek
            {
                get { return dayOfWeek; }
                set
                {
                    if (dayOfWeek != value)
                    {
                        dayOfWeek = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("DayOfWeek");
                    }
                }
            }

            private string morning = "unset";
            public string Morning
            {
                get { return morning; }
                set
                {
                    if (morning != value)
                    {
                        morning = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Morning");
                    }
                }
            }

            private string evening = "unset";
            public string Evening
            {
                get { return evening; }
                set
                {
                    if (evening != value)
                    {
                        evening = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Evening");
                    }
                }
            }

            private double total;
            public double Total
            {
                get { return total; }
                set
                {
                    if(total != value)
                    {
                        total = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Total");
                    }
                }
            }


            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

'SchedUpdate' property is mentioned bellow:

```
private List<ScheduleData> schedUpdate;
        public List<ScheduleData> SchedUpdate
        {
            get
            {
                return schedUpdate;
            }
            set
            {
                if (schedUpdate != value)
                {
                    schedUpdate = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SchedUpdate");
                }
            }
        }
```

I think i have shared maximum detail regarding the code in which i am getting error. Please help in resolving this error.

Comment: Remove `qoutes` from `@t` in your query `total='@t'`

Comment: Got it! Thanx @Leopard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given `qoutes` around parameter name `@t` which is not required. Remove qoutes from `@t` in your query `total=@t`

Also don't concatenate values in query use Parameterized Sql just like you are adding value of parameter `@t`